# NextJs13 & Shadcn UI Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: __webpack_require__.n is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I am facing a very weird bug with an almost empty NextJs project.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Create NextJs13 project
   `npx create-next-app@latest my-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint`
2. Init shadcn
   `npx shadcn-ui@latest init`
3. Add a few ui components
   `npx shadcn-ui@latest add button label input`
4. Create login form with the following component:

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";

interface UserAuthFormProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {}

export function UserAuthForm({ className, ...props }: UserAuthFormProps) {
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

 async function onSubmit(event: React.SyntheticEvent) {
   event.preventDefault();
   setIsLoading(true);

   setTimeout(() => {
     setIsLoading(false);
   }, 3000);
 }

 return (
   <div className={cn("grid gap-6", className)} {...props}>
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
       <div className="grid gap-2">
         <div className="grid gap-1">
           <Label className="sr-only" htmlFor="email">
             Email
           </Label>
           <Input
             id="email"
             placeholder="name@example.com"
             type="email"
             autoCapitalize="none"
             autoComplete="email"
             autoCorrect="off"
             disabled={isLoading}
           />
         </div>
         <Button disabled={isLoading}>
           {isLoading && (
             <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
           )}
           Sign In with Email
         </Button>
       </div>
     </form>
     <div className="relative">
       <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center">
         <span className="w-full border-t" />
       </div>
       <div className="relative flex justify-center text-xs uppercase">
         <span className="bg-background px-2 text-muted-foreground">
           Or continue with
         </span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <Button variant="outline" type="button" disabled={isLoading}>
       {isLoading ? (
         <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
       ) : (
         <Icons.gitHub className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
       )}{" "}
       Github
     </Button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Error:
When I start the app in dev mode and go to the url of the page I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: __webpack_require__.n is not a function. (In '__webpack_require__.n(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__)', '__webpack_require__.n' is undefined)
```

The error doesn't appear in production. If I turn off code minifying and compression in webpack to debug the issue I also don't get the error in dev mode.

Webpack config without code minifying & compression

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = (nextConfig) => {
    return {
      ...nextConfig,
      compress: false,
      webpack(webpackConfig) {
        return {
          ...webpackConfig,
          optimization: {
            minimize: false
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
```

I run out of ideas to further debug the error.

Do you know where the error is coming from or how I can debug it further?

I have added a git repo to easily reproduce the error here in case anyone wants to try their luck:
https://github.com/JanRuettinger/nextjs-error/tree/master

EDIT:
I figured out that the bug only appears in Safari.

Comment: I just clonned your repo, executed `npm run dev` and go to localhost:3000/login and the error didnt appeared, maybe its your nodejs version? mine is 16.15

Comment: Oh good point, I am on v20.2.0. 

I just tried it with:
lts/hydrogen -> v18.17.0 => didn't work,
lts/gallium -> v16.20.1 => works!

That's weird. Ideally I don't want to go back to such an old node version. Do you have an idea how to debug it further. I can't imagine that such a simple setup can't be run with a more up to date node version. Can you maybe also try v18.17.0, or v20.2.0?

Comment: both versions doesnt throws error  :)

Comment: Hm that's so weird. It doesn't work for me on an Apple M2. Do you have ideas how can I debug it further?